# Nginx failing to serve django static or media files on digital ocean

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

I'm having issues serving static files and media files when I deploy my dockerised django app to digital ocean. I've read many similar questions on here, but none of the answers have worked for me so far.

Roughly following this guide, https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#nginx, I'm now in a state where I can spin up my docker container locally using the following commands and have nginx serve static/media files perfectly:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml down -v
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

I'm now attempting to get the same working on a digital ocean droplet. On the remote server I run exactly the same commands as above start up the services. Everything then works as expected apart from the ability to access any static or media file. Whenever I for example visit {my digital ocean ip}/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css, I'm met with a 404 error. Whenever I see chrome attempting to fetch my custom css, the requests just show as "cancelled" (and then if I visit the URL path of the cancelled request I see the same 404).

My code can be seen here: https://github.com/PaulGilmartin/personal_website
Parts perhaps relevant to this discussion:

nginx.conf

```
upstream personal_website {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://personal_website;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/personal_website/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/personal_website/media/;
    }

}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I'm especially confused that the exact same commands work perfectly locally. This made me think that the 404s on the remote server are a permission based symptom, but I don't see how that can be the case as in my Dockerfile.prod I'm careful to chown everything to the non-root user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm running low on ideas of what the issue could be!

Edit: Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'


services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn personal_website.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 120
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/var/www/personal_website/static
      - media_volume:/var/www/personal_website/media
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/var/www/personal_website/static
      - media_volume:/var/www/personal_website/media
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Comment: Show your docker-compose file

Comment: @IvanStarostin edited to add it :)

Comment: Check `collectstatic` output. Could be user WWW does not have permission to write anything to mentioned volumes. Perhaps you meant chown to `$APP_HOME` in your dockerfile, not `$HOME`.

Comment: I think since APP_HOME is contained within HOME and the `chown` was recursive, that part should be fine? I can see `www` is owner of output of all files, including the output of collectstatic:

```www@86c0586098e9:/var/www/personal_website$ ls -l
...
drwxr-xr-x 3 www www 4096 May  2 19:46 media
drwxr-xr-x 1 www www 4096 May  2 15:58 nginx
drwxr-xr-x 4 www www 4096 May  2 19:46 static
drwxr-xr-x 1 www www 4096 May  2 11:32 templates
www@86c0586098e9:/var/www/personal_website/static$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 6 www www 4096 May  2 19:46 admin
drwxr-xr-x 2 www www 4096 May  2 19:48 css
```

Comment: I've noticed that my nginx.conf file has root only privileges, might that make a difference? I guess that comes about because of the nginx/Dockerfile config

paul@web:~/personal_website$ sudo docker exec 0431ab4ac863 ls -l /etc/nginx/conf.d/
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           425 May  2 15:58 nginx.conf

Comment: It can be permissions issue caused by running containers under specific, existing only in this container users because other containers don't know about such users and are running under different users. Can be fixed/should be organized by docker user mapping, but is more related to mapping to host users (I'm not a pro in this questions, so can't tell for sure if this is the case). However if it was a permission issue then nginx should contain 403 in logs, not 404. My guess in prior comment was that if it is about permissions then files don't get written to those folders which leads to 404.

Comment: Also 1337 port was used in the tutorial for whatever reason but in your case I don't think it's necessary to keep using it. Also see this, can be image/digitalocean issue https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-doesn-t-http-my_ip_address-port-work-on-my-droplet

Comment: For some reason I cannot view the nginx logs directly. When I try

`paul@web:~/personal_website$ sudo docker exec 0431ab4ac863 tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/access.log`

the command appears to just get stuck. Similar commands work however - the following works fine:

`paul@web:~/personal_website$ sudo docker exec 0431ab4ac863 cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`

Comment: Tried removing the 1337 port, no luck. Also tried changing $host in the nginx conf to $http_host, still no luck.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I can see the following in my nginx erorr logs:

`/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist, exiting`

I'm assuming that's from Dockerfile I have for the nginx service. Any idea what this error could be? Dockerfile:

`FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d`

Comment: Removing that RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf got rid of that error, but didn't help the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that the issue is here:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

This path should actually be the same as nginx expecting:

```
/var/www/personal_website/static/
```

Thus, you can try the following things:

1. Try to hardcode static root in Django settings:

   `STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/personal_website/static/'`
2. Do bash into the container where Django is running: `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash` - run there collectstatic and check whether static files are copied to the folder you expected. If not - then you may want to find, where exactly the files are copied.
3. Also check inside nginx container if it also sees the correct volume with static files

I had quite the same issue and hardcoding paths for static and media solved the issue

**Update:**
I've cloned the project and for me, it didn't pick up static files. So I did the following changes in **docker-compose-prod.yml** and it became to work:

1. Remove **ports** from services - **web**:

   ```
   ports:
      - "80:8000"
   ```

It is not needed as web (Django) should not be accessible from outside. Only internally in Docker on exposed port 8000

2. Set open port of nginx to 80:

   ```
   ports:
      - 80:80
   ```

I don't know which port is used by DigitalOcean to host the site, but the default is 80.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do help. I could already see that the static files were being correctly moved to '/var/www/personal_website/static/' in the container and that STATIC_ROOT was resolving correctly, so wasn't holding out much hope. I think if that had been the issue, it wouldn't be working locally either.

Comment: @PaulGilmartin see the update of my answer. Advise if it helped

Comment: That did it! I had originally added ports to the web service because I couldn't get the website running at all without it (I suppose because I had 1337:80 in the nginx service, rather than 80:80 used by Digital ocean). Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I guess you ended up reaching Django from outside i.o. nginx because of ports: 80:8000 on "web".